# Making vimperator ctrl+ keybindings work on sites like Wikipedia

Tags: macos, firefox, vimperator

Vimperator uses keybindings like ctrl+o for go-back-one-page-in-history.

Some sites on teh interwebs try to be more accessible by binding keyboard commands to specific actions, for example Wikipedia (and every other wikimedia site I have encountered) maps `ctrl+o` to the login command (or at least something that requires a login).

So, I'm browsing happily along, and happen to follow a link to Wikipedia. If I want to go back a page, vimperator has trained me to ctrl+o. However, this keystroke is captured before vimperator can do anything with it, and I am taken to the Wikipedia login page. Do. Not. Want.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox on Mac OS X uses the `ctrl` key as the Access Key by default, which causes the to be consumed before it reaches any other plugins.

To fix, edit the value of `ui.key.contentAccess` in `about:config`. By default in OS X, the value is 2, which corresponds to the bitfield for using the `ctrl` key as Access Key for the content area (as opposed to chrome area).

The other values are `0` for `disable`; `1` for `shift`; `4` for `alt`; `8` for `meta` (`command`). I set mine to 4, but any value other than 2 should work.

Once that is done, the `ctrl+` keybindings should work as expected. If you use other vimperator keybindings, be sure to set the `ui.key.contentAccess` value to something that does not clash with your bindings, or disable it entirely.

Comment: The numeric values can also be summed as you'd expect. `6` would correspond to `⌃⌥` (the default in Safari and Chrome.)